# AWS S3 Bucket name already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, undelete

I in S3 Buckets if ill create a new one or Bucket name already exists
but I can I have two visible buckets.

**Edit:**

In other words, my bucket's been orphaned and I cant see it to delete it and I cannot recreate as per image:

[image]

Comment: Bucket names are globally unique, so if it already exists then it already exists. I can't tell anything from your image, because the only valuable information is redacted.

Comment: but its not visible

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/7p6qqIB.png](IMAGE)

Comment: if you create a new bucket, AWS warns about this, just read before you click :-) (create bucket > behind "Bucket name" hover above the blue circle with "i" for information and there you can read it)

Comment: Why negative votes? The question makes sense. You may improve the text, rather than giving negative votes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

S3 bucket names are **globally unique**. This means that if someone else has a bucket of a certain name, you cannot have a bucket with that same name.

So if you are trying to create a bucket, and AWS says it already exists, then it already exists, either in your AWS account **or someone else's AWS account**.

Answer (score 3):

Just be careful if you use Cloud Formation to create S3 buckets and go and manually delete things... you can end up with an orphaned bucket that you cant see, and cannot recreate. This just happened to me and when it happens to you its easier to understand OP's explanation.

Another way you can get into this pickle is retaining resources when you delete a stack:

[image]